# Please help provide a simple example to encode for protobuf in dart

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

Can anyone please help provide a simple example to encode data for protobuf in dart...

Fully understand how to decode the protobuf data received from a server in the browser...

```
MyMessage.fromBuffer(binaryDataList);
```

Not sure how to encode the data to protobuf in the browser to send back to the server..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `writeToBuffer()` on your message to get a list of bytes that you can send via AJAX or Websockets. The returned buffer is of the type [`Uint8List`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_typed_data/Uint8List.html) that implements [`List<int>`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/List.html).

Comment: Thanks.. was on this track.. but maybe having trouble in the dart2js conversion..

Comment: Works fine for me with dart2js.

Comment: Thanks.. Fox32.. now all my versions.. sdk.. libraries.. are in line.. all is good..